# Ubuntu 16.4 public Samba share suddenly not public anymore

Tags: samba, windows-10, ubuntu-16.04

New, completely "vanilla" Ubuntu 16.4 server installation. I modified the original smb.conf file to include a public share. It worked, until I rebooted the Windows 10 client. Now, I get asked for the credentials when trying to access the public share. They work, but the share is supposed to be public, so something is obviously wrong. What I cannot fathom is how it could have worked, and then suddenly not anymore after a Windows reboot. There's nothing in the Windows Credential Manager, and it shouldn't be either.

Here's the smb.conf file (which has NOT been altered after it worked the first time):

```
[global]
workgroup = WORKGROUP

Server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)

dns proxy = no[global]

log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m

max log size = 1000

syslog = 0

panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d

server role = standalone server

obey pam restrictions = yes

unix password sync = yes

passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .

pam password change = yes

map to guest = bad user

usershare allow guests = yes

[printers]
   comment = All Printers
   browseable = no
   path = /var/spool/samba
   printable = yes
   guest ok = no
   read only = yes
   create mask = 0700

[print$]
   comment = Printer Drivers
   path = /var/lib/samba/printers
   browseable = yes
   read only = yes
   guest ok = no

[public]
   comment = Public share
   path = /home/public
   browsable = yes
   read only = no
   guest ok = yes
   force user = nobody
```

Anyone got any ideas? The workgroup "WORKGROUP" is the same. The permissions and ownership of the public folder on the server are correct. Etc. Etc.